# iOS - UITextView dismiss keyboard in storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, keyboard

I have a UITextView in which users could type some notes and save them. I want to dismiss the keyboard when the user drags on the edge of the keyboard and pull it down (just like in Message). I see that in storyboard -> attributes inspector -> Scroll View -> Keyboard, there is a drop down menu where I can choose the way of dismissing the keyboard. I've tried both Dismiss on drag and Dismiss interactively but nothing happens. I've tried setting the view controller that manages the text view to be the delegate, but there does not seem to be a method through which I can interact with the keyboard. Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar issue. I had a `UITextView` located in one of the cells of a `UITableView`. Setting a Keyboard attribute of the TextView to "Dismiss on drag" didn't work. The solution was to set the **TableView's** attribute Keyboard to "Dismiss on drag".

I think that your ScrollView might be contained in some other control, e.g. TableView. Then it is the container that performs the scrolling. If that is the case you should set the container's Keyboard attribute to "Dismiss on drag".

If that doesn't work then my other suggestion is that you don't have enough content in your ScrollView to actually do the scrolling. I would make sure that you have the length of your ScrollView's content large enough so it doesn't fit the screen.

Let me know if any of these worked.

Comment: You're right - once I have enough things so that notes don't fit in one screen I can drag to dismiss the keyboard. I was also misunderstanding what it means by "Dismiss on drag". I thought it means dragging on the edge of the keyboard, but it's instead dragging on the text view. Now things are clear to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe (I haven't tried it and I am not very experienced) you could add an `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to the main view (maybe you'll have to change the main view "Custom Class" to `UIControl`) and then call `[self.view endEditing:YES]` from its action method?